# Wordpress Titles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mixpanel

I have a post title with an ' in it. Wordpress is outputting this encoded as an HTML entity (`I&#8217;m` for example), but when I use that to track events in analytics like Mixpanel, I don't get a nice human-readable title, I get the title with the HTML entity, obviously. I've been searching and tried several things, but nothing seems to work.

Here's my current code.

```
mixpanel.track("Episode View", {
"Title": epNum + " <?php wp_kses_decode_entities(the_title()); ?>",
"Episode Number": epNum,
"Season": 1
```

Can someone point me to a way to decode a string that say, contains an `'` and then escape it for javascript?

Comment: you can escape single and double queotes with a backslash in js and php too.

Comment: Yes, if you're hardcoding the string. I'm pulling it from a database.

Comment: it doesn't matter. `str_replace("'". "\\'", wp_kses_decode_entities(the_title()));`

Comment: wait. `the_title();` echoes it, so you need to use `get_title();`

Comment: But if it's not decoding string, there's nothing to escape. That's my point `wp_kses_decond_entities` still outputs an encoded string, even with `get_the_title`